# Java: util.Date object in long format

Tags: java, jackson

How can I return a Date object with a long value?
Something like:

```
@JsonProperty("time")
    public Date getTimeInLong() {
       Date date = super.getTime();
       return date.getTime() //I want this value as date object
    }
```

Reason is that I am trying to override a JSON property `time` to long format. But if I change getter  signature to `public long getTime(){}`, I get `Conflicting getter definitions for property "time":` exception from

Comment: `new Date (date.getTime())`

Comment: Why convert a `Date` to a `long` and immediately convert it back again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `@JsonFormat`annotation with the `shape = Shape.NUMBER` parameter on the existing getter method. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonJsonFormat {
    public static class Bean {
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
        public Date getTime() {
            return new Date();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Bean()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"time":1406068019124}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question you can just do:

```
return new Date(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Better yet, `return date;`

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use it like this:

```
@JsonProperty("time")
    public Date getTimeInLong() {
       Date date = super.getTime();
       return  new Date (date.getTime());
    }
```